# Failed to create appium session for android

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, appium-inspector

I have followed a youtube tutorial to setup for appium and it gets done also. But I'm facing an issue of failed session while running `Appium Inspector` for my emulator. I have tried many available solutions but it's not working for me. Please find the error message below and guide me if you're aware to resolve it. I'm using 4723 as the remote port here.

[image]

Comment: Did you try providing `appActivity` without the preceding `.`? Also it is possible that you cannot launch directly into that activity, maybe you have a SplashActivity?

Comment: There is no splash activity in my project. MainActivity is the launcher. I have tried by mentioned complete package name also but din't work. Even I tried to paste .apk in downloads folder but that also din't work.